# Does OSGI solve the absence of AppDomains in Java?

Tags: java, .net, osgi, appdomain

I mean some aspects, such as isolating different versions of the same artifact by different ClassLoaders like .Net allows isolating assemblies by different AppDomains.

Comment: Your question as currently phrased requires knowledge of both .Net AppDomains and OSGi. That combination of skills is rare. I know a lot about OSGi but very little about .Net, so if you describe what specific features of AppDomains are missing from Java then I can tell you if OSGi is a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. OSGi is a way to structurally define and enforce boundaries and dependencies between different parts of an application.

What it is not, is an application container, where different applications can live more or less unaware of each other, like a servlet container such as Tomcat.

There are solutions to do both, such as Apache Karaf, which is basically an OSGi based application container. In those containers every application gets its own OSGi environment.

Comment: Wait, Karaf doesn't implement OSGi Subsystems yet, does it? In what sense then does Karaf provide additional isolation of "applications" over what is provided by core OSGi?

Comment: I think Karaf 3.0 with its latest version of Aries can do that (but haven't tried that yet). What I mean is that you can deploy isolated  osgi sub-instances, which is, correct me if I'm wrong, similar to .Net AppDomains.

Comment: I don't think so. I believe (but could be wrong) that App Domains in .NET include not just module loading isolation also isolation of memory, CPU usage etc. Nothing like this exists in OSGi due to limitations of the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

@ Frank

"Apache Karaf, which is basically an OSGi based application container. In those containers every application gets its own OSGi environment."

I don't think so. When you deploy an OSGi component inside Karaf (or ServiceMix), you cannot specify a specific application. e.g. like:  osgi:install  componentX.jar Application1

So it seems like there is NO application boundary. All OSGi modules deployed within the same SMX or Karaf instance can see each other and import each other's functionality.

For SMX, which is an ESB, this sucks....

Can anyone confirm this?

Also... some OSGi modules are just libraries, some are applications (e.g. listen to a port to do something).

I think everything is running on 1 JVM...

Someone please confirm this also...

Appdomains are something else. OSGi does not provide this concept. Do we need it?

Comment: There is a notion of 'instances' and 'features' in Karaf which provide  boundaries. Different like AppDomain. I am not sure wheater each instance has it's own JVM.